# Multiple joins into one column

Tags: mysql

I have query that LEFT joins information from two tables. With code with following joins

```
LEFT JOIN A on source = news_id 
LEFT JOIN B on source = other_news_id
```

How can join or display data from the two columns so it produces one column information.

```
ID  source    Left Join on ID a   Left Join on ID b   
a    1            info1             <null>
a    2            info2             <null>
b    3            <null>            info3
b    4            <null>            info4
```

Something along the lines of

```
ID  source   info
a    1       info1             
a    2       info2
b    3       info3             
b    4       info4
```

How can I bring all left joins into one column?

Comment: Are there rows that have both `a.id` and `b.id` not null? If yes, the order inside the `COALESCE()` function matters (the first non-null will be chosen). If no, you may be able to rewrite the query with a `UNION` of 2 queries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `COALESCE()` if there will always only be one value.  It returns the first non-null argument.

```
SELECT ID, source, COALESCE(infoa, infob) AS info FROM ...
```

Comment: i don't always have value, occasionally its a null but this work exactly like I need, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The `COALESCE` function will do this.

See the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) for examples of how to use this function.

Answer (score 2):

From the sample data, it seems that no `A.news_id` is never equal to a `B.other_news_id` and the two columns you want to `COALESCE` have at least one `NULL` value.

I also guess your `FROM` clause is something like this:

```
FROM  T
  LEFT JOIN A on T.source = A.news_id 
  LEFT JOIN B on T.source = B.other_news_id
```

If that's the case, you could also rewrite the query with a `UNION`:

```
SELECT ID, source, infoa AS info
FROM  T
  JOIN A on T.source = A.news_id 
WHERE ...

UNION ALL

SELECT ID, source, infob
FROM  T
  JOIN B on T.source = B.other_news_id
WHERE ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you need to use INNER JOINs instead of LEFT JOINs